# How to put value from input to the paragraph tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
var innerValue = $('.edit-location').val(); // i am getting value from input

var locationText = $('.location-text').text(); // i am getting inner text from target paragraph

$('.save-button').click(function () {
   innerValue =  locationText; // i am putting value from input to the paragraph 
    $('.popup-block').removeClass('active'); // hiding popup with input
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

Replace

`innerValue =  locationText;`

by

`$('.location-text').text($('.edit-location').val());`.

#### Explanation:

jQuery's `.text()` function can work as a `getter`, but also as a `setter`.

If you pass no argument to it, it ***returns*** the current text of the element which you called it on.

If you pass a `String` to it like in  `.text("Hello!")` it works as a setter that sets the element's text to the `String` you pass.

#### Second problem

```
var innerValue = $('.edit-location').val();
```

Please note that the content of `locationText` is read ***only once at the moment of execution of that line*** - your line of code does not cause any form of data binding, which means `locationText` will **not** automatically change when the value of that input changes. So make sure to read the input value at exactly that moment when you need it.

So this is what your code needs to look like:

```js
$('.save-button').click(function () {
   $('.location-text').text($('.edit-location').val()); // i am putting value from input to the paragraph 
   // $('.popup-block').removeClass('active'); // hiding popup with input
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="edit-location" />
<p class="location-text">Placeholder text until you click this button below:</p>
<button type="button" class="save-button">Save</button>
```

Comment: Its just delete previous text from the paragraph tag

Comment: So what do you want? You want to **append** the value from the input to `locationText`?

Comment: I need to type some text to the input, and by click on the button, this text should appear in the paragraph tag,

Comment: Yeah, my updated answer will do just that. `$('.location-text').text($('.edit-location').val());`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to append the values? You can use `$(SELECTOR).text(YOUR_VARIABLE)` to set the inner text of the `<p>` tag.